# Biq Query: Regexp_Contains (like in !:))

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, bq

I need return true, when data in one column contain some word from another table column and use their in Case When. How I can fix it (But I can`t use join or cross join, because I need all data  from left table)?

[image: SQL]

[image: Need result]

Comment: Please add you sample data (input) and the expected output.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.  You talk about two tables in the question, but show three tables in the sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need return true, when data in one column contain some word from another table column

I find that this often works simplest to summarize the second table as a regular expression and use that:

```
select m.*,
       (case when regexp_contains(m.name, d1.pattern) then 'organic'
             when regexp_contains(m.name, d2.pattern) then 'social'
        end) as source
from main_table m cross join
     (select string_agg(name, '|') as pattern
      from dictionary_1
     ) d1 cross join
     (select string_agg(name, '|') as pattern
      from dictionary_2
     ) d2;
```

Comment: I can't use cross join because I need all information from Left table

Comment: @EugenSkotarenko . . . You comment doesn't make sense.  This returns all the rows from `main_table`.

Answer (score 0):

In cases when dictionary are lengthy - regexp pattern itself can become expensive affecting query performance. Try below approach as an option

```
select name,
  case 
    when (select logical_or(regexp_contains(t.name, name)) from dictionary_1) then 'organic'
    when (select logical_or(regexp_contains(t.name, name)) from dictionary_2) then 'social_media'
    else 'other'
  end source
from Main_table t
```

Comment: Thanks for help. I checked. Seems like correct result